# Using Gmail as a registration confirmation letter sender

Tags: java, email, gmail, registration

I would like to create a web-site that is going to send a lot (expected 1000 mails in one day) of emails with registration confirmation links at once. Java Mailing + Spring is used to send emails. Is it alright to choose Gmail as a service to send my mails? I think there are some frequency/amount limitations there. If it is not how this things have to be done could you suggest other services or ways of sending big amount of mails? (f.e. would it be okay, if I use several mail services?)

Comment: Why don't you ask the google folks directly; instead of relying on hear-say of other people; that might or might not have an exact understanding of the policies of Google? Besides: you are asking about legal stuff, and off site resources, so you are pretty much **off-topic** anyway.

Comment: Yes, but I also would like to know if there any reliable services that could satisfy my needs, or if it is a totally wrong way of doing that

Comment: And again, that is **not** what this site should be used for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GMAIL - Then you're limited to 500 recipients per 24 hours. If you upgrade to google apps you will get increased sending limits..

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852

If you want to go the FREE route, you'll need to spin up your own mail server and use it.